# Meteor says 'this.register' is not a function

Tags: meteor

When I try to subscribe in my Meteor app, it gives me the following error :

```
Exception from Tracker recompute function:
debug.js:41 TypeError: _this.register is not a function
    at subscriptions [as _subscriptions] (routes.js:59)
    at Route.callSubscriptions (route.js:60)
    at router.js:427
    at Tracker.Computation._compute (tracker.js:323)
    at Tracker.Computation._recompute (tracker.js:342)
    at Object.Tracker._runFlush (tracker.js:481)
    at Object.Tracker.flush (tracker.js:441)
    at Router._invalidateTracker (router.js:489)
    at afterAllTriggersRan (router.js:101)
    at Object.Triggers.runTriggers (triggers.js:89)
```

Here's how I tried to subscribe through the router :

```
FlowRouter.route('/new-page/simple-page', {
  name:          'newSimplePage',
  subscriptions: () => {
    this.register('newPages', Meteor.subscribe('newPages'));
    this.register('pageHeaderImages', Meteor.subscribe('pageHeaderImages'));
  },
  action () {
    BlazeLayout.render('panelLayout', {
      content: 'NewSimplePage',
    });
    setTitle('New Simple Page');
  },
});
```

I also tried to add the subscription in the template and faced the same error. I use Meteor 1.3 beta 6. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Yeah, don't use arrow functions when you use `this` unless you want to preserve an existing context. Here, you're basically forcing `subscriptions` to be bound to `global` (or wherever Meteor binds that code) so FlowRouter can't rebind it and it bonks. Instead, follow the short-hand syntax used below with `action()` or write a good old function `function() { /* ... */  }`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because you are using a fat arrow function. The [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) state that it:

> ...lexically binds the this value (does not bind its own this, arguments, super, or new.target)

To summarize, that means that `this` will be set to whatever the `this` is outer scope. Most commonly, it is used to avoid the `var self = this` line before the scope of `this` changes.

`subscriptions` binds a `thisArg` to allow you to use `this.register`. Simple solution though:

```
subsciptions: function () {
  this.register()
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to use the fat arrow function and let `this` behave in the old way?

Comment: not to sound rude, but why would you want to? Most of the purpose of arrow functions is so you can avoid `var self = this; doTheThing(function () { /**...*/ });`